# Swift 2.0 Defer Not working in XCode 7.0.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, ios9

I have a simple block of code with a defer block, but playground is not executing the defer block. What am I doing wrong?

The following gets printed:
"Step 1"
"Step 3"
"Step 4"
"Step 5"

```
import UIKit

print("Step 1")

do {
    defer { print("Step 2") }
    print("Step 3")
    print("Step 4")
} 

print("Step 5")
```

Comment: Are you sure? Works for me.

Comment: for me it is working in project but it isn't working in playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are looking at console? If so, there must be bug in playground. Here is what I got from your code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/En6kn.png

Comment: I see Oct  3 03:21:05  defer[4160] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

Comment: that's actually bug in iOS playground in Xcode 7. Look at Apple Developer forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a bug in `playground`.

If you try this code

```
var d = 0
print("Step 1")

    do {
        defer {
            d = 1
        }
        print("Step 3")
        print("Step 4")
    }
    print(d)
    print("Step 5")
```

You will see the value `d` is updated to the value `1`, so the statement is called.

There must be a bug, your code is fine.